# Can tfdbg be run with Cloud ML Engine training job?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

I cannot find any examples of the tfdbg tool being run with a cloud ML engine. This [post](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) shows how to wrap a tensorflow session with the debugger, but I have not encountered any way to run an ML engine package in debug mode. Has anybody found a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

CloudML Engine does not support the interactive CLI debugger.

However, you should be able to use the [offline debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger#offline_debugging_of_remotely-running_sessions). How you get it to work in your case will depend on how your code is structured.

Suppose your code is written to accept a `--job-dir` command-line argument. When you submit your job you will have something like this:

```
export JOB_NAME=my_job
export JOB_DIR=gs://my_bucket/$JOB_NAME
gcloud ml-engine jobs training submit ... --job-dir=$JOB_DIR ...

# Start with this code.
from tensorflow.python import debug as tfdbg

# job_dir is on GCS and is passed on the command-line if you specify
# it when submitting your training job.
dump_dir = os.path.join(job_dir, 'tfdbg_dumps')
```

For more info on `watch_fn`, see [docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/debug/wrappers/framework.py#L799).

**Core TensorFlow (User-created Session)**

If you're using "core" TensorFlow, i.e., creating your own session, then will replace the construction of any tf.Session objects like so:

```
sess = tfdbg.DumpingDebugWrapperSession(sess, dump_dir)
sess.run(fetches=my_fetches, feed_dict=my_feed_dict)
```

See [DumpingDebugWrapperSession docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/DumpingDebugWrapperSession#__init__) for more info.

**Estimator API**

If you are using `learn_runner` or `Experiment`, you can use [`DumpingDebugHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/DumpingDebugHook):

```
experiment = Experiment(
  ...,
  train_monitors =[tfdbg.DumpingDebugHook(dump_dir)],
  ...
)
learn_runner.run(experiment)
```

Unfortunately, I cannot see a way to use filters such as `tfdbg.has_inf_or_nan` except with [`LocalCLIDebugHook`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/LocalCLIDebugHook), so you'll just have to analyze the tensors offline.

**Offline analysis**

Once the data is available in GCS, you can examine the dumps using the provided `offline_analyzer` executable module. You'll have to choose one of the run sub directories:

```
python -m tensorflow.python.debug.cli.offline_analyzer \
    --dump_dir=$JOB_DIR/tfdbg_dumps/run_XXXXXXX
```

Comment: How would this be modified if I was running an experiment with learn_runner instead of sess.run directly? Is this worth a separate question or would it be best to update the answer here to cover both cases?

Comment: Also, would an example of the watch_fn be the tfdbg.has_inf_or_nan if we are looking to debug why the loss is diverging to NaN?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: I think this is working, but want to note some peculiar behavior I am seeing and understand if it is intended.  When I go to the job logs it shows the loss at step 1 but then it stops (although the job still says running) and nothing else is being output into the job logs.  When I look in GCS, there does appear to be some stuff in tfdbg_dumps folder, but when I run --dump_dir=$JOB_DIR I got the error "Dump file path does not conform to the naming pattern: %s" % base)
ValueError: Dump file path does not conform to the naming pattern: checkpoint"

Comment: Separately I ran with --dump_dir=$JOB_DIR/tfdbg_dumps and I got a separate error "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: The specified path gs://..jobdirhere../tfdbg_dumps/gs://..jobdirhere../tfdbg_dumps/run_1509727304147533_0/_tfdbg_core_metadata_sessionrun00000000000025_1509727305971236 was not found." which I am also not really sure how to interpret. Any idea what is going wrong? Would the job need to complete before the tfdbg_dumps are available to run the offline_analyzer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I found a bug in offline_analyzer and have submitted a patch. I'll have to see if TensorFlow team will be willing to backport the fix. In the meantime, perhaps I can send you the patch directly. What version of TF are you using?

Comment: It appears that offline_analyzer will work with absolute paths. So until the tool is patched, copy one or more of the run* directories to your local machine /VM and provide the absolute path.

Comment: I am trying to run through this again and never found a way to run tfdbg on the model. How can I run in the context of tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate()? would I need to pass a train_monitor to my tf.estimator.RunConfig?

Comment: You can add hooks to the TrainSpec passed to Estimator.train_and_evaluate()